# Git clone failure

Tags: git, make

I've compiled git (configure && make) 2.35.3 on centos and ssh clone succeed but https clone fails with

`fatal: unable to access '/root/etc/gitconfig': Permission denied`

My git config is in my home directory since that's where I have git installed. I don't have access to root and therefore the path is unavailable to me.